# Saltstack: different versions for Master and Minion

Tags: linux, configuration, configuration-management, saltstack

I've a little-big problem. I've an architecture with dozens of servers, everyone having a different OS.

- My **Master** is on an Ubuntu Server 14.04 and its version is *0.17.5*.
- My **Minions are of different versions**, included *0.17.5* and, for example, *2015.5.0* on an Ubuntu 12.04 precise.

When Master-Minion have the same version ID, all is executed correctly. When they mismatch, I receive the following message when I call a `state.highstate`:

- **`No Top file or external nodes data matches found`**

This message is strange, because the top file is in the right place (`/srv/salt/top.sls`), I've set the `file_roots: base: - /srv/salt`, with the correct syntax) and I've set "`base: '*'`" (with the correct syntax) in my `top file`.

Do you have any idea on how to manage different version of Master-Minion or how can I upgrade the previous version of my Minion (on old OSs) to the most recent one?
Thank you very very much for your support !!!

Answer (score 2):

I answer to myself:
After having added the PPA with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:saltstack/salt` I forgot to execute an update of apt get `apt-get update` and then updating the master with `apt-get install --only-upgrade salt-master`

Thank you by the way :)